# Javascript: Split an array according to a pattern: items 1, 5, 10, then 2, 6, 11, then 3, 7, 12

Tags: javascript, arrays, split

I am trying to split an array which has a repeating pattern of elements 1, 2, 3, and 4. I want to turn my array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] into four arrays: [1,5,10], [2,6,11], [3,7,12], and [4,8,13]. I tried using multiples, but the result creates the new arrays in a wrong order. Here is my attempt:

```
var upload_names_and_ids = [

    "Certificat de salaire", //first line is the upload's visible title
    "certificat-de-salaire", //second line is the upload's id
    "no-info-circle", //third line is the info-circle class
    "", //fourth line is the info-circle text
    
    "Allocations Familiales",
    "alloc-familiales",
    "no-info-circle",
    "",
    
    "Courrier Impot (déclaration précédente)",
    "courrier-impot",
    "info-circle right",
    ""
    
];

//Seperate our first array into 4

var upload_names = [];
var upload_ids = [];
var upload_info_circle_class = [];
var upload_info_circle_content = [];

for (var i=0; i<upload_names_and_ids.length; i++){
    if (i%4==0) {
        upload_info_circle_content.push(upload_names_and_ids[i]);
    } else if (i%3==0) {
        upload_info_circle_class.push(upload_names_and_ids[i]);
    } else if (i%2==0) {
        upload_names.push(upload_names_and_ids[i]);
    }   else {
      upload_ids.push(upload_names_and_ids[i]);
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take a remainder with index and wanted length.

```js
const
    array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16],
    length = 4,
    result = array.reduce(
        (r, v, i) => (r[i % length].push(v), r),
        Array.from({ length }, _ => [])
    );

console.log(result);
```

If you like to use predeclared array directly, you could replace this line

```
Array.from({ length }, _ => [])
```

with

```
[upload_names, upload_ids, upload_info_circle_class, upload_info_circle_content]
```

where the accumulator of [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) keeps the object references.

Comment: Thank you that makes sense to me. However I'm quite new to this, and unsure where exactly to insert the names of my new arrays? The four names upload_names, upload_ids, upload_info_circle_class, and upload_info_circle_content

Comment: Great I followed your edit and it worked! Thank you so much! Hallelujah!

Answer (score 1):

It's not `i%3==0` (which matches 0, 3, 6, …) but `i%4==1` (to match 1, 5, 10, …). Same for `i%2==0`.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a helper `sliceN` that takes an array and a positive integer. Then returns an array of arrays where the inner arrays are of length `n`.

```
sliceN([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 3) //=> [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
sliceN([1,2,3,4,5,6], 2) //=> [[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]
```

Then also add a helper `transpose` that [transposes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transpose) a matrix.

```
transpose([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]) //=> [[1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9]]
transpose([[1,2], [3,4], [5,6]]) //=> [[1,3,5], [2,4,6]]
```

With these two helpers you can create the wanted result with ease.

```js
const upload_names_and_ids = [
    "Certificat de salaire", //first line is the upload's visible title
    "certificat-de-salaire", //second line is the upload's id
    "no-info-circle", //third line is the info-circle class
    "", //fourth line is the info-circle text
    
    "Allocations Familiales",
    "alloc-familiales",
    "no-info-circle",
    "",
    
    "Courrier Impot (déclaration précédente)",
    "courrier-impot",
    "info-circle right",
    ""
];

const [
  upload_names,
  upload_ids,
  upload_info_circle_class,
  upload_info_circle_content,
] = transpose(sliceN(upload_names_and_ids, 4));

console.log(upload_names);
console.log(upload_ids);
console.log(upload_info_circle_class);
console.log(upload_info_circle_content);


function sliceN(array, n) {
  const slices = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i += n) {
    slices.push(array.slice(i, i + n));
  }
  return slices;
}

function transpose(rows) {
  if (rows.length == 0) return [];
  const columns = rows[0].map(cell => Array.of(cell));
  for (let iRow = 1; iRow < rows.length; iRow += 1) {
    for (let iCol = 0; iCol < columns.length; iCol += 1) {
      columns[iCol].push(rows[iRow][iCol]);
    }
  }
  return columns;
}
```

If you are already use a library with helper functions chances are that one or both of these data transforming methods are present. `sliceN` can often be found as something with `split`, `slice` or `chunk` in the name. `transpose` is very specific and if present will probably be present under the same name.

As an example [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com) offers both these methods.

```
R.transpose(R.splitEvery(4, upload_names_and_ids))
```